# How do I change property of class listing in scripting dictionary?

Tags: applescript

[image]

I saw the property I want to modify in an application scripting dictionary. It is located in a class, but I can’t find a way to modify it. Is there a way to modify it?

I tried the following methods, but I got an error:

```
tell application "Capture One 21"
    activate
    
    set image location of next capture options to "/tmp"
end tell
```

output:

```
error "Can’t set «class viil» of «class CncO» to \"/tmp\"." number -10006 from «class viil» of «class CncO» to «class /tmp»
```

The error code -10006 means "The write operation was denied".

When I used `get image location of next capture options` to try to get this configuration, I also got an error:

```
tell application "Capture One 20"
    activate
    
    get image location of next capture options
end tell
```

output:

```
error "Can’t get image location of next capture options." number -1728 from «class viil» of «class CncO»
```

-1728 means "The referenced object doesn’t exist."，but I'm using an pro version.

[image]

Comment: I notice there’s a note at the top of that section in the scripting dictionary that suggests using those properties requires an enterprise license. Might that be the problem? I don’t see any obvious errors in the code you’re using. Can you try *displaying* any of those settings first? (e.g.: log image location of next capture options)

Comment: I used the professional version of the app for testing, but still can’t achieve the functionality I want

Comment: Looks like Pro and Enterprise are separate products, (or licences/prices at least): https://www.captureone.com/en/products-plans/multiuser-enterprise Not sure if this is the issue. I think it might be, if printing those values (never mind setting them) is also a problem.

Comment: Indeed, pro and enterprise are not the same, it is very likely that this is the problem, although it still can not be solved, but thank you

Comment: Maybe, the dictionary is not updated. To see real existing hierarchy (object model) use Script Debugger and litte  script: **tell application "Capture One 20" to set appObjectModel to it**.

Comment: As to 'location', try entering a location as specified within the app, rather than an external file reference. As to your last error, your syntax doesn't look right to me. Try `get image location`, lose the 'of next…' as it is redundant. And really, start with the easy: `get next capture options`. As others suggest, putting aside these issues, your version may not support these particular properties — Enterprise ≠ Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [@Robert Kniazidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9862669/robert-kniazidis) for your help. Using Script Debugger, I found that the actual setting item is not `next capture options`, but `next capture settings`, and it is located under `document`, so the actual way to get this configuration value is  `get image location of next capture settings of document 1`. But in the end it really can't be set up, because the enterprise version is required.

[image]

In the end, I found a way to simulate and manipulate UI elements to achieve the effect I wanted:

```
tell application "Capture One 20"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Capture One 20"
        click radio button 2 of radio group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        
        global destination
        set destination to 0
        
        repeat with g in every group of window 1
            
            repeat with sa in every scroll area of g
                if exists of group "NextCaptureLocation" of sa then
                    set nextCaptureLocation to group "NextCaptureLocation" of sa
                    
                    if exists of group "目的地" of nextCaptureLocation then
                        set destination to group "目的地" of nextCaptureLocation
                    end if
                    
                    if exists of group "Destination" of nextCaptureLocation then
                        set destination to group "Destination" of nextCaptureLocation
                    end if
                end if
            end repeat
            
        end repeat
        
        if destination = 0 then
            display notification "Cannot obtain target element Destination" with title "AppleScript Error"
            return
        end if
        
        click pop up button 1 of destination
        click menu item -1 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of destination
        delay 1
        key code 5 using {shift down, command down}
        delay 1
        key code 0 using {command down} -- command + A
        key code 51
        delay 1
        set the clipboard to "/tmp"
        key code 9 using {command down} -- command + v
        delay 1
        keystroke return
        delay 1
        keystroke return
        
    end tell
end tell
```